# Ubuntu 23.04 No deja instalar paquetes npm

Tags: nodejs, linux, ubuntu, docker, npm

Tengo la pc recien formateada, sin nada instalado. No estoy tras un proxy
pero cuado quiero hacer `npm i` queda "colgado", al ver los logs y googlear
dice que son problemas de proxy. Me parecio raro y volvi a formatear
ahora con todo limpio decidi usar `devcontainer` de vscode para directamente usar
un "docker", ya que pensaba que el problema era de npm, pero tampoco puedo continuar
con las instalaciones dentro del contenedor...

cat /etc/environment me devuelve:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
```

`env | grep -i proxy` no retorna nada.

Ingrese con otra pc con windows y todo funciona correctamente, asi que la red no creo
que sea...

OS Name: Ubuntu 23.04
OS Type: 64-bit
kernel version: Linux 6.2.0-34-generic

La formatee a ubuntu 22 y tampoco hay solucion.

Comment: estas ejecutando un doker o un docker makefile que te da el comando `npm ping`

Comment: @John, no es un docker en si ,como cuando creas el *dockerfile* sino que estoy usando una extension de *vscode* llamado *Dev Containers* el cual me dice en los logs que no puede descargar los paquetes.Creo que me pasa lo mismo que al de este post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76828091/error-when-trying-to-build-a-dev-container-from-vscode?newreg=c02a7713406945c5b73e8743ad2f6244

Comment: y el npm ping? por que si no responde pues estas siendo bloqueado por algún cortafuegos

Comment: tras formatear la pc 5 veces y probar diferentes distros y versiones, se me dio por reiniciar el modem y todo volvio a la normalidad. Ignoro si lagun paquete quedo colgado en el router o si eso es posible, pero al reinicarlo como ultiima opcion, ya no tuve mas problemas de este tipo....

Answer (score -1):

Al no haber proxy o vpn como podemos ver en otros post
de stackoverflow. Reiniciar el modem fue la solucion.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres? ¿Cuál model?

Comment: @fredyfx creo que se refiere al moden

Comment: Aaaahhhh, vale, entendido. Seguro ha sido de esos bugs bien raros. La infalible reiniciada de modem y santo remedio :D